# How to bind a function to a Progressbar?

Tags: c#

I want to create a wrapper that will bind a function to a progressbar such that I will call it  alike ProgressBar.ReportProgressFor(MyDefinedFunction()) in c#.How can I do that?
I want to make a function that will take an user defined function as its parameter and execute it and return the percentage of the user defined function executed in a method property .How can I do that?Please help me
The code example should be like
var x= ProgressBar.ReportProgressFor(MyDefinedFunction());
and to get the executed percentage we will use
x.RemainingPercentage   and x.ExecutedPercentage

Comment: Please give some example

Comment: Please specify your current context. It's not obvious if you're developing a desktop app, or mobile app, or which framework you already use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Delegates. Create a delegate for the method that displays the progress and from your main task, attach it there.

Comment: please give the code